# I get a System.ArgumentException when running MSTest tests for a console app that contains a Main method without args

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, mstest

I have a basic console application developed in C# 10, which is designed for .NET 6.0. The app receives the complete file path as input, verifies its existence, and logs a message to the console indicating whether it exists or not. Additionally, I have a unit test project implemented with MSTest, containing three tests that cover all possible scenarios and code statements. However, when I execute the tests in either Visual Studio 2022 or through the command prompt, I encounter the following error for each test: "System.ArgumentException: Argument --parentprocessid was not specified."

Here's the code for the main program.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a file path (or 'exit' to quit):");
            string? filePath = Console.ReadLine();

            if (filePath?.ToLower() == "exit")
                break;

            bool fileExists = File.Exists(filePath);
            if (fileExists)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File exists.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File doesn't exist.");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Here's the code for the unit tests.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestHost;

namespace FileCheckTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public partial class UnitTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void FileExists_ShouldPrintFileExists()
        {
            string filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
            var consoleOutput = new ConsoleOutput();

            using (consoleOutput)
            {
                Console.SetIn(new StringReader(filePath));
                Program.Main(null);
            }

            string output = consoleOutput.GetOutput();
            Assert.IsTrue(output.Contains("File exists"));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void FileDoesNotExist_ShouldPrintFileDoesNotExist()
        {
            string filePath = "NonExistentFile.txt";
            var consoleOutput = new ConsoleOutput();

            using (consoleOutput)
            {
                Console.SetIn(new StringReader(filePath));
                Program.Main(null);
            }

            string output = consoleOutput.GetOutput();
            Assert.IsTrue(output.Contains("File doesn't exist"));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ExitCommand_ShouldExitProgram()
        {
            string filePath = "exit";
            var consoleOutput = new ConsoleOutput();

            using (consoleOutput)
            {
                Console.SetIn(new StringReader(filePath));
                Program.Main(null);
            }

            string output = consoleOutput.GetOutput();
            Assert.IsFalse(output.Contains("File exists") || output.Contains("File doesn't exist"));
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here's the class the unit tests use to handle the console output.

```
namespace FileCheckTests
{
    public partial class UnitTests
    {
        private class ConsoleOutput : IDisposable
        {
            private StringWriter stringWriter;
            private TextWriter originalOutput;

            public ConsoleOutput()
            {
                stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                originalOutput = Console.Out;
                Console.SetOut(stringWriter);
            }

            public string GetOutput()
            {
                return stringWriter.ToString();
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                Console.SetOut(originalOutput);
                stringWriter.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So far, I've done the following to try to resolve the exception:\

1. Updated MSTest framework and test adapter.
2. Rebuilt the solution.
3. Cleaned the solution.
4. Restarted Visual Studio.
5. Added the default string[] args back to the Main method signature and passed an empty array of strings into the Program.Main() call for each test.

Comment: Why are you defining Main without parameters and then calling Main passing `null` as a parameter value? As you have defined it, Main must be called as `Program.Main();`

Comment: Hey @JonathanDodds I removed the string[] args because the IDE told me it wasn't being used. If I call it as Program.Main(), then it complains about There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'args' of 'Program.Main(string[]?)'. This is interesting because Main's signature doesn't have an array of strings parameter.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: The standard definition is `static void Main(string[] args)`. When you don't use a parameter, you remove the name i.e. `static void Main(string[])`.

Comment: I think I've got some work to do. It looks like I'm trying to integration test the app since console input and output are required for the checks. I think I need to separate the business logic out and try to write unit tests for that.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is: you didn't reference the target project in your test project.

So, the `Program` in your test will use 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestHost' as default class definition.

Hover to 'Program' and see what it is. Reference the target project, the issue should disappear.